# Why do Phantom, Casper, and Meteor need their own executables?

Tags: node.js, meteor, phantomjs, casperjs

<del>Phantom</del> and Meteor are built off Node, and Casper is built off Phantom. Why do they each need their own separate executable, rather than being libraries you `require` through Node.js?

(I find it makes them harder to work with, especially on Windows.)

Comment: Well, not sure about meteor, but Phantom doesn't seem to actually use Node. It just has some of the same inspirations (esp. CommonJS) and implements a few similar modules (fs, child_process). Best guess on meteor is just that it wants control over how the project is structured.

Comment: Nirk is correct. The require when using Phantom is the CommonJS library, not node: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference#module-api ... and yes I have found that PhantomJS and windows dont always play nice together. USE LINUX!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

phantomjs is completely separate from node:

http://phantomjs.org/faq.html

> Q: Why is PhantomJS not written as Node.js module?
>
> A: The short answer: "No one can serve two masters."
>
> A longer explanation is as follows.
>
> As of now, it is technically very challenging to do so.
>
> Every Node.js module is essentially "a slave" to the core of Node.js, i.e. "the master". In its current state, PhantomJS (and its included WebKit) needs to have the full control (in a synchronous matter) over everything: event loop, network stack, and JavaScript execution.
>
> If the intention is just about using PhantomJS right from a script running within Node.js, such a "loose binding" can be achieved by launching a PhantomJS process and interact with it.

CasperJS is built on top of node, so it obviously isn't a node module by itself.  Although in that case, you can use [SpookyJS](https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS) with node.

Meteor really should be more tightly coupled with node.  There's a similar framework [Derby](http://derbyjs.com/) built for use as a module.